# Error opening android camera for streaming video

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I'm trying to write video stream from my Galaxy Tab to server. 
according to [this manual](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video) i should do something like this:

```
        frontCamera = getFrontCamera();
        if((socket!= null)&&(frontCamera!=null))
        {
            try {
                frontCamera.setPreviewDisplay(cameraPreview.getHolder());
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("","",e1);

            }
            frontCamera.startPreview();
            recorder =  new MediaRecorder();
            frontCamera.unlock();
            recorder.setCamera(frontCamera);
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
            recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
            recorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get( CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
            pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(socket);
            recorder.setOutputFile(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
            recorder.setPreviewDisplay(cameraPreview.getHolder().getSurface());
            try {
                recorder.prepare();
                recorder.start();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("","",e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("","",e);
            }
```

but all fails on step `recorder.start();` with strange error

```
02-01 19:03:39.265: E/MediaRecorder(11922): start failed: -19
```

what does that mean and  what should I do to start recorder?

UPD:
 Trouble happens because of my getFrontCamera method. when I replace it with camera.open() all works correct.

```
protected Camera getFrontCamera()
{
    Camera.CameraInfo inf = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    for(int i = 0; i< Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++)
    {

        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, inf);
        if(inf.facing==Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
        {
            return Camera.open(i);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Upd2 - yes, explicit setting of format and encoders solved the trouble -

```
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
```

Maybe because of pre-build formats are for back camera... But strange anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see output format setup, so try adding to recorder set up:

```
 recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: this is being done with recorder.setProfile(...) as far as I understand.

Comment: Oh, I tracked down to that -19 is the value of NO_INIT and most probably returned from setupCameraSource when (*cameraSource)->initCheck() is not OK.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem with that mysterious error -19 on Nexus S on IC 4.0.4. So, what it worked for me was explicitly setting the frame rate to <15 FPS and video size to 320x240.

Comment: @nifo Were you ever able to record at higher than 15fps? I am using the galaxy nexus which claims to be able to record at 24fps, but it crashes in the same way when I try to go higher than 15. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156509/can-i-record-android-video-at-more-than-15fps

Answer (score 0):

Have a [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186503/camera-app-not-working/10187932#10187932)

And though it is streaming video, so that set -

```
recorder.setOutputFormat(8);
recorder.setOutputFile(socketFd);
```

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

I've a hack here, extending media recorder class and removing super.setVideoFrameRate(rate) solves the problem for me.

Comment: That's the same as not calling it. Not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use `CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH` with the front camera, you can use the following:

```
CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(currentCameraId, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
recorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile);
```

where `int currentCameraId` is `Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK` or `...FRONT`

So the profile is indeed dependent on the camera (for high-end phones it appears to work fine without the distinction, since they all support 1080p by now, but low-end phones may crash otherwise)