# java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed

Tags: android, android-permissions, forceclose, android-mediarecorder

I am trying to record audio in one of my Activities using MediaRecorder. Part of the code is shown below.

```
File file = new File(AppConstants.MSGS_DIR, filename);
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
recorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
try {
    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

I've given the following permissions in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

but at the line *recorder.start()* I am getting the runtime exception. Logcat shows the following error messages.

```
09-23 15:47:54.462: E/AndroidRuntime(8697): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 15:47:54.462: E/AndroidRuntime(8697): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mypackage/com.mypackage.RecordingActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
09-23 15:47:54.462: E/AndroidRuntime(8697):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
09-23 15:47:54.462: E/AndroidRuntime(8697):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2300)
09-23 15:47:54.462: E/AndroidRuntime(8697):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144)
09-23 15:47:54.462: E/AndroidRuntime(8697):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1295)
09-23 15:47:54.462: E/AndroidRuntime(8697):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-23 15:47:54.462: E/AndroidRuntime(8697):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
09-23 15:47:54.462: E/AndroidRuntime(8697):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5162)
09-23 15:47:54.462: E/AndroidRuntime(8697):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 15:47:54.462: E/AndroidRuntime(8697):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-23 15:47:54.462: E/AndroidRuntime(8697):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:744)
09-23 15:47:54.462: E/AndroidRuntime(8697):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-23 15:47:54.462: E/AndroidRuntime(8697):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-23 15:47:54.462: E/AndroidRuntime(8697): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
09-23 15:47:54.462: E/AndroidRuntime(8697):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
09-23 15:47:54.462: E/AndroidRuntime(8697):     at com.mypackage.RecordingActivity.startRecording(RecordingActivity.java:169)
09-23 15:47:54.462: E/AndroidRuntime(8697):     at com.mypackage.RecordingActivity.onCreate(RecordingActivity.java:107)
09-23 15:47:54.462: E/AndroidRuntime(8697):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5288)
09-23 15:47:54.462: E/AndroidRuntime(8697):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-23 15:47:54.462: E/AndroidRuntime(8697):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2214)
```

Tried questions corresponding to the error in stackoverflow but unable to conclude a valid answers from them. Please check this and help me which is going wrong in the code.

FYI> this piece of code failing in only specific devices. Am I missing any additional permissions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10497885/1777090

Comment: @MysticMagic I am looking for audio recording which i feel nothing to do with width and height. The answer you ponited out is for video recording :)

Comment: _this piece of code failing in only specific devices_ - you may want to include more details about those devices. Like, what's the platform version on them? `AudioEncoder.AMR_WB` is available only from API10.

Comment: @shoerat: Code not working in the devices:<i> sony ericson of version 4.0.3, ASUS Genfone of version 4.3</i>. Code working fine in Moto-g 4.4.4, Note 2 of OS version 4.4.2.

Comment: What's `AppConstants.MSGS_DIR`? Where does it point to?

Comment: @shoerat AppConstants.MSGS_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/MYAppFolder/"; and file name is some random string. I am able to create the folder and file (with fileName0 in that folder successfully but not able to write any data to it.

Comment: _but not able to write any data to it_ --- So, probably, that's the cause of the exception? Maybe try with different paths (e.g., `Context.getExternalFilesDir()`?

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Few of the devices are not supporting because they do not support 3GP format as well as AudioEncoder.AMR_WB encoding. Click [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) to check the supported formats.

Please use below code which will support maximum number of devices.

```
recorder.setOutputFormat(OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AAC);
```

Comment: How about android 2.2 ?

Comment: Whats about android M??

Comment: Will making it Default work for every device ?. like below recorder.setOutputFormat(OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Api 23 then make permission granted first then start recording

```
     private boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
            int permissionSendMessage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            int locationPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
            List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
            if (locationPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
            }
            if (permissionSendMessage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
            if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
      @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Permission callback called-------");
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {

                Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<>();
                // Initialize the map with both permissions
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                // Fill with actual results from user
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                        perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
                    // Check for both permissions
                    if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                            && perms.get(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "sms & location services permission granted");
                        // process the normal flow

                        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
                        pager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
                        tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
                        tabs.setViewPager(pager);
                        //else any one or both the permissions are not granted
                    } else {
                        Log.d("TAG", "Some permissions are not granted ask again ");
                        //permission is denied (this is the first time, when "never ask again" is not checked) so ask again explaining the usage of permission
//                        // shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return true
                        //show the dialog or snackbar saying its necessary and try again otherwise proceed with setup.
                        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ||
                                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {
                            showDialogOK("SMS and Location Services Permission required for this app",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            switch (which) {
                                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                                    checkAndRequestPermissions();
                                                    break;
                                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                                    // proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                        //permission is denied (and never ask again is  checked)
                        //shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return false
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Go to settings and enable permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                            //                            //proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void showDialogOK(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", okListener)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
```