# android mediarecorder error (MediaRecorder start failed : -19)

Tags: android, mediarecorder

When I try to make the camera recorder in my program I get this error:

> E/MediaRecorder﹕ start failed: -19

code is

```
try {
    final SurfaceView sv = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.srvView);
    MediaRecorder mrec = new MediaRecorder();
    mrec.setCamera(camera);

    mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mrec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mrec.setVideoFrameRate(10);
    mrec.setVideoSize(480, 320);
    mrec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mrec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);

    mrec.setPreviewDisplay(mSh.getSurface());
    mrec.setOutputFile("/mnt/sdcard/pro/andsend.avi");
    mrec.prepare();
    mrec.start();
} catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I try to change the sequence and change the set size, Frame Rate etc...

But, I can't find the problem.

What's the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android MediaRecorder - "start failed: -19"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496969/android-mediarecorder-start-failed-19)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see my answer : [android-mediarecorder-start-failed-19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496969/android-mediarecorder-start-failed-19/32985263#32985263)

error code -19 comes about when there is a problem with the size of the video as set by `MediaRecorder#setVideoSize()`

Answer (score 0):

```
 mrec.setOutputFile("/mnt/sdcard/pro/andsend.avi");
```

are you sure that this folder exist? Also edit this line to

```
mrec.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/pro/andsend.avi");
```

Comment: folder exist. When I test, mrec.start() occupy error.