# mediaRecorder:start() function failed

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

I am trying to capture a video using `mediaRecorder`.

Here is my Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    MediaRecorder recorder;
    File outfile = null;
    static final String TAG = "MediaRecording";
    Button startButton,stopButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    }

    public void startRecording(View view) throws IOException {
        startButton.setEnabled(false);
        stopButton.setEnabled(true);
        //Creating file
        File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        try {
            outfile = File.createTempFile("video", ".mp4", dir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "external storage access error");
            return;
        }

        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setOutputFile(outfile.getAbsolutePath());
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    }

    public void stopRecording(View view) {
        startButton.setEnabled(true);
        stopButton.setEnabled(false);
        //stopping recorder
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
    }
}
```

However, when i click on the startrecording button i get an error at the line `recorder.start()`

> > Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.

I have the following permissions in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

edit: as requested, here is th full logcat.

```
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.android.update, PID: 19656
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4096)
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856)
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19956)
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4091)
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856) 
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19956) 
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389) 
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020) 
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815) 
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.android.update.MainActivity.startRecording(MainActivity.java:74)
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4091) 
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856) 
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19956) 
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389) 
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020) 
11-25 13:08:08.701 19656-19656/com.example.android.update E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

Comment: Can you post full logcat ?

Comment: @Ginso I tried with your code, it is working fine.

Comment: could the camera perhaps be somehow blocked by something else? is there a way to find out, wheter it is "free"?

Comment: @Ginso refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/4379320/5567009

Comment: apart from the fact that all those example use deprecated stuff, i tried the first example and got the same error

Comment: This is how I solved the start problem (github project inside): http://stackoverflow.com/a/35270647/1596613