# Mediarecorder.start() RuntimeException: start failed android 4.0.4

Tags: android, camera, runtimeexception, video-recording

Tried to make an camera app and have followed googles developer guide, but I get an runtimeException: start failed on my android 4.0.4 device. However it works on my friends 4.2.X Samsung. Tried to google the problem but haven't found any relevant solution.

Error Code

```
05-13 18:16:06.458: E/MediaRecorder(32701): start failed: -19
05-13 18:16:06.468: E/AndroidRuntime(32701): java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
05-13 18:16:06.468: E/AndroidRuntime(32701):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
05-13 18:16:06.468: E/AndroidRuntime(32701):    at com.example.cameeera.Main.onClick(Main.java:61)
```

Main Class

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.CamcorderProfile;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;

    private boolean isRecording = false;
    Button captureButton;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Create an instance of Camera
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.button_capture){
            if (isRecording) {
                // stop recording and release camera
                mMediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
                releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
                mCamera.lock();         // take camera access back from MediaRecorder

                // inform the user that recording has stopped
                captureButton.setText("Start");;
                isRecording = false;
            } 
            else {
                // initialize video camera
                if (prepareVideoRecorder()== true) {
                    // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared,
                    // now you can start recording
                    mMediaRecorder.start();

                    // inform the user that recording has started
                    captureButton.setText("Stop");
                    isRecording = true;
                } 
                else {
                    // prepare didn't work, release the camera
                    releaseMediaRecorder();
                    // inform user
                }
            }
        }
    }//OnClick


    private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(){

        //mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder ();

        // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
        mCamera.unlock();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

        // Step 2: Set sources
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
        //mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
        CamcorderProfile highCameraProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
        mMediaRecorder.setProfile(highCameraProfile);
        mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(100000); // MAXDuration 10 seconds
        mMediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(20000000); // MAXSIZE 20 megabytes


        // Step 4: Set output file
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(SaveVideoFile.getOutputMediaFile(SaveVideoFile.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());

        // Step 5: Set the preview output
        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

        // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
        try {
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d("TAG", "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("TAG", "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }//prepareVideorecorder



    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseMediaRecorder();       // if you are using MediaRecorder, release it first
        releaseCamera();              // release the camera immediately on pause event
    }

    private void releaseMediaRecorder(){
        if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
            mMediaRecorder.reset();   // clear recorder configuration
            mMediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
            mMediaRecorder = null;
            mCamera.lock();           // lock camera for later use
        }
    }

    private void releaseCamera(){
        if (mCamera != null){
            mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){   
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
            Log.d("TAG", "Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)" + e.getMessage());
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }





}
```

Here is the CameraPreview class, works fine
package com.example.cameeera;

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

/** Camera preview class */

    public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        public SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
          // preview surface does not exist
          return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
          // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("TAG", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try answers from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249642/mediarecorder-start-failed-19

Comment: Try this CamcorderProfile highCameraProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW)