# MediaRecorder start failed: -16

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

So I realize there are many solutions out there for MediaRecorder start errors, however most of them revolve around "start failed: -19", which has been linked to "NO_INIT" [See comments in selected answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098216/error-opening-android-camera-for-streaming-video).  I haven't found any solution, or even an explanation for -16.

If someone knows where i can find the names of these error codes, or has a solution for code -16 Please put the answer here!!  Here is the code I'm using. (HTC Thunderbolt, Stock)

```
mr.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA); //mr is my mediaRecorder
mr.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mr.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
mr.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
mr.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
mr.setOutputFile(ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(soc).getFileDescriptor());  //soc is a java.net.ServerSocket pointing to a port on the device

mr.setVideoSize(480,800);
mr.setVideoFrameRate(5);
mr.prepare();
mr.start(); //Crashes with "start failed: -16"
```

LOGCAT

```
07-11 10:14:34.879: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): JNIMediaRecorderListener::setCamera
07-11 10:14:34.879: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): process_media_recorder_call
07-11 10:14:47.549: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): setVideoSource(1)
07-11 10:14:47.549: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): getMediaRecorder E
07-11 10:14:47.559: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): process_media_recorder_call
07-11 10:14:47.559: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): setAudioSource(1)
07-11 10:14:47.559: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): getMediaRecorder E
07-11 10:14:47.559: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): process_media_recorder_call
07-11 10:14:47.559: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): setOutputFormat(0)
07-11 10:14:47.559: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): getMediaRecorder E
07-11 10:14:47.559: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): process_media_recorder_call
07-11 10:14:47.559: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): setVideoEncoder(0)
07-11 10:14:47.559: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): getMediaRecorder E
07-11 10:14:47.559: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): process_media_recorder_call
07-11 10:14:47.559: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): setAudioEncoder(0)
07-11 10:14:47.559: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): getMediaRecorder E
07-11 10:14:47.559: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): process_media_recorder_call
07-11 10:14:47.559: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): setVideoFrameRate(5)
07-11 10:14:47.559: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): getMediaRecorder E
07-11 10:14:47.559: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): process_media_recorder_call
07-11 10:14:47.559: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): setOutputFile
07-11 10:14:47.559: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): getMediaRecorder E
07-11 10:14:47.559: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): process_media_recorder_call
07-11 10:14:47.559: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): prepare
07-11 10:14:47.559: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): getMediaRecorder E
07-11 10:14:47.559: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): process_media_recorder_call
07-11 10:14:47.559: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): start
07-11 10:14:47.559: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): getMediaRecorder E
07-11 10:14:47.639: E/MediaRecorder(17939): start failed: -16
07-11 10:14:47.639: V/MediaRecorderJNI(17939): process_media_recorder_call
07-11 10:14:59.290: W/dalvikvm(17939): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
```

**UPDATE 07/11/12 2:21 PM**: Discoverd the the error code -16 is actually -EBUSY.  After expanding the LogCat to include everything, and combing thorough the Android source code, I found that its related to an inablility to adjust (initialize) the camera settings, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but its a start. If you have access to AOSP you can see that the error comes from /frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/CameraSource.cpp CameraSource::ConfigureCamera

Answer (score 2):

I ran in to this error (-16 on start) and found out it was caused by using an unsupported resolution.

First you have to get the optimal size from the supported sizes

```
Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        List<Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        optimalSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, width, height);
params.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);
```

Then make sure you set both preview and video to the same size (if they were different in my experience preview would freeze when video record started):

```
mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);
```

(sample code for getOptimalPreviewSize is from android sdk)

```
private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
    if (sizes == null) return null;

    Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    int targetHeight = h;

    // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
    for (Size size : sizes) {
        double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
        if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
        }
    }

    // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Size size : sizes) {
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
    }
    return optimalSize;
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the error. My Question posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964349/mediarecorder-start-failed-16-when-change-camcorderprofile-quality-low-to-camc

Comment: "Make sure you set both preview and video to the same size (if they were different in my experience preview would freeze when video record started):",This solved my problem,Thank You