# MediaRecorder start failed: -16 when change CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW to CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH

Tags: android, mediarecorder

> Posical duplicate [MediaRecorder start failed: -16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434972/mediarecorder-start-failed-16)

MediaRecorder start failed: -16 when change `CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW` to `CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH`. I have tried many solutions but getting the same error.

following is the my code:

```
private boolean prepareVideoRecorder() {

        if(mMediaRecorder == null){
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        }else{
            Log.d(Constants.TAG,"MediaRecoder is Not Null");
        }
        // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.unlock();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

        // Step 2: Set sources
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
//      Size optimalSize = new Size(320,240);
//      int  width=320, height=240;
//      Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
//        List<Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
//        optimalSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, width, height);
//        params.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);
//        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);
          CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(mCamSelect, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
            if(profile == null){
                Log.d(Constants.TAG, "the camcorder profile instance is null");
            }
        // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
        mMediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);

        // Step 4: Set output file
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());

        // Step 5: Set the preview output
        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

        // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
        try {

            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Logcat:

```
04-12 11:09:14.396: V/MediaRecorderJNI(19761): start
04-12 11:09:14.396: V/MediaRecorderJNI(19761): getMediaRecorder E
04-12 11:09:14.466: E/MediaRecorder(19761): start failed: -16
04-12 11:09:14.466: V/MediaRecorderJNI(19761): process_media_recorder_call
04-12 11:09:14.466: D/AndroidRuntime(19761): Shutting down VM
04-12 11:09:14.466: W/dalvikvm(19761): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
04-12 11:09:14.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19761): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-12 11:09:14.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19761): java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
04-12 11:09:14.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19761):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
04-12 11:09:14.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19761):    at uk.org.humanfocus.hfi.RecordVideoActivity.captureButtonHandler(RecordVideoActivity.java:218)
04-12 11:09:14.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19761):    at uk.org.humanfocus.hfi.RecordVideoActivity.onClick(RecordVideoActivity.java:100)
04-12 11:09:14.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19761):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2533)
04-12 11:09:14.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19761):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9320)
04-12 11:09:14.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19761):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-12 11:09:14.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19761):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-12 11:09:14.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19761):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
04-12 11:09:14.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19761):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
04-12 11:09:14.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19761):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-12 11:09:14.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19761):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-12 11:09:14.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19761):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
04-12 11:09:14.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19761):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
04-12 11:09:14.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19761):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Did you fix this? Agar ho gya the to please reply.

Comment: Yes fixed. Code posted in answer. Up vote if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this problem.

Following is the my working code.

```
    private boolean prepareVideoRecorder() {

        if(mMediaRecorder == null){
            mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        }else{
            Log.d(Constants.TAG,"MediaRecoder is Not Null");
        }

        // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.unlock();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);


         // Step 2: Set sources
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        // Step 3: Set output format and encoding (for versions prior to API Level 8)
        CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
        camcorderProfile.videoFrameWidth = 640;
        camcorderProfile.videoFrameHeight = 480;
//      camcorderProfile.videoFrameRate = 15;
        camcorderProfile.videoCodec = MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264;
//      camcorderProfile.audioCodec = MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC;
        camcorderProfile.fileFormat = MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4;

        mMediaRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile);

        // Step 4: Set output file
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());

        // Step 5: Set the preview output
        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

        // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
        try {

            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this worked. But you have hardcoded the `camcorderProfile.videoFrameWidth` and `camcorderProfile.videoFrameHeight`. Is there any way to set them to default values?

Comment: @AdilMalik IT WAS MY REQUIREMENT. You can try by commenting these lines.

Comment: I already tried that. But it didn't work. I had to use another code that I found on a blog. Your code works fine if someone doesn't have strict requirements for resolution.